# Leaflet map incorrect rendering in PrimeFaces Dialog

Tags: html, css, primefaces, leaflet

Try to input Leaflet map into PrimeFaces Dialog. And I have a issue with incorrect rendering. Map has incorrect position, looks like map start positioning relative to index.html not to the Dialog. The next issue: size is incorrect. The same code outside the dialogue works fine. How to change this?

```
<h:head>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition> 
            <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>           
            <p:dialog  id="map" header="Mapa:" widgetVar="wigetMapDialog" height="800px" width="1200px" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip" resizable="false" closable="true" dynamic="true" modal="true">               
                <div id="mapid" style="width: 1180px; height: 780px;"></div>  
                <script>
                    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([50.9547215, 16.9126256], 18);
                    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    }).addTo(mymap);
                </script>
            </p:dialog> 
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>     
</html>
```

My Dialog:

[image]

When I move map inside:

Comment: Looks like the symptoms of missing the Leaflet CSS file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue Leaflet map tiles in wrong order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723390/vue-leaflet-map-tiles-in-wrong-order)

Comment: No, but changed a little result. But still it is incorrect.

Comment: When changes the browser window size (for example: to full screen) map render again and then it looks ok

Comment: ...and that's the symptom of missing the initial size of the map container, which can be worked around with `invalidateSize()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742326/why-isnt-my-map-completely-showing

Comment: This is not really PrimeFaces relates but more HTML and CSS. If you provided the rendered HTML you have a higher chance of getting an answer.

Comment: You hopefully know that all code **OUTSIDE** the `ui:composition` is **ignored**... So the css will not do anything! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500894/how-to-change-head-elements-of-a-page-when-using-uicomposition

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have two problems.

1. The first one being that [everything outside a `ui:composition` is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500894/how-to-change-head-elements-of-a-page-when-using-uicomposition)
2. Every non visible (`display: none`) html element has [no width when retrieved with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472303/jquery-get-width-of-element-when-not-visible-display-none)

The first issue can be solved by adding the css inside the `ui:composition`. The second one, getting the dimensions of a non-visible PrimeFaces (with `display: none` in the relevant rendered html code) is not (easily) solveable via the way mentioned in the link above. This is the case with many frameworks, so other frameworks, like mentioned by @IvanSanchez, often have methods to recalulate the dimensions when something *is* shown. So should call the mentioned `invalidateSize()` in the `p:dialog onShow="..."` like

```
<p:dialog ... onShow="mymap.invalidateSize()">

...
</p:dialog>
```

might solve the issue (disclaimer: not tried this, no computer at hand to try it)

Answer (score 0):

This i my solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
       mymap.invalidateSize();});
</script>
```

Thank you for a hint.