# Sharing a state store object to child components in Vue (without Vuex)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to follow [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) tutorial on how to use a store pattern to share state between Vue components.

In the tutorial, they initialize two separate and independent Vue instances:

```
var vmA = new Vue({
  data: {
    privateState: {},
    sharedState: store.state
  }
})

var vmB = new Vue({
  data: {
    privateState: {},
    sharedState: store.state
  }
})
```

But I am using components defined in separate .vue files in a `components` file, so I don't have anywhere to specify `data`. I can't put it in the `export default` block because there is already a `data()` entry there, for example in my component `LeafletMap.vue`:

```
<template>
    <!-- ref="map" is required or Leaflet-Draw throws TypeError: "_this.$parent.$parent.$refs.map is undefined"  -->
    <!-- See: https://github.com/hubertokf/vue2-leaflet-draw/issues/1#issuecomment-520572130 -->
  <l-map
      ref="map"
      v-if="showMap"
      :zoom="zoom"
      :center="center"
      :options="mapOptions"
      @update:center="centerUpdate"
      @update:zoom="zoomUpdate"
    >
      <l-draw-toolbar position="topright"/>
      <l-tile-layer
        :url="url"
        :attribution="attribution"
      />
    </l-map>
</template>

<script>

import { latLng } from "leaflet";
import { LMap, LTileLayer } from "vue2-leaflet";
import LDrawToolbar from 'vue2-leaflet-draw-toolbar';

export default {
  name: "LeafletMap",
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LDrawToolbar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latLng(8.6195, 0.8248),
      url: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      currentCenter: latLng(47.41322, -1.219482),
      showParagraph: false,
      mapOptions: {
        zoomSnap: 0.5
      },
      showMap: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    zoomUpdate(zoom) {
      this.currentZoom = zoom;
    },
    centerUpdate(center) {
      this.currentCenter = center;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And in my App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="sidebar-container">
      <Sidebar />
    </div>
    <div id="map-container">
      <LeafletMap />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import LENIInterface from './components/LENIInterface.vue'
import LeafletMap from './components/LeafletMap.vue'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar.vue'

export default {
  name: 'xyz',
  components: {
    LeafletMap,
    Sidebar,
  }
}
</script>
```

And in main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export

// Leaflet tiles are scrambled unless you add this import
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723390/vue-leaflet-map-tiles-in-wrong-order
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
// import "./assets/css/main.css";

Vue.config.productionTip = false

var store = {
  debug: true,
  state: {
    message: 'Hello!'
  },
  setMessageAction (newValue) {
    if (this.debug) console.log('setMessageAction triggered with', newValue)
    this.state.message = newValue
  },
  clearMessageAction () {
    if (this.debug) console.log('clearMessageAction triggered')
    this.state.message = ''
  }
}

new Vue({
  data: {
    privateState: {},
    sharedState: store.state
  },
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

So how can I pass this state store object down to the subcomponents when they are organized like this?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a file called store.js:

```js
export default {
  state: {
    message: 'Hello!'
  },
  methods: {
    setMessageAction (newValue) {
      if (this.debug) console.log('setMessageAction triggered with', newValue)
      this.state.message = newValue
    },
    clearMessageAction () {
      if (this.debug) console.log('clearMessageAction triggered')
      this.state.message = ''
    }
  }
}
```

And import it in your LeafletMap.vue:

```js
<script>

import { latLng } from "leaflet";
import { LMap, LTileLayer } from "vue2-leaflet";
import LDrawToolbar from 'vue2-leaflet-draw-toolbar';
import store from './stores/store.js';

export default {
  name: "LeafletMap",
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LDrawToolbar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latLng(8.6195, 0.8248),
      url: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      currentCenter: latLng(47.41322, -1.219482),
      showParagraph: false,
      mapOptions: {
        zoomSnap: 0.5
      },
      showMap: true
      ...store.state
    };
  },
  methods: {
    zoomUpdate(zoom) {
      this.currentZoom = zoom;
    },
    centerUpdate(center) {
      this.currentCenter = center;
    }
    ...store.methods
  }
};
</script>
```